# How to get values from database into the instamojo function in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have specified some values in variables and got some values from database. I wanted to assign these values into the pay_request(). Can anyone tell how to do this ? `$profile_data['stud_name']`,`$profile_data['stud_email']` and `$profile_data['stud_mobile']` is obtained from the database.

```
$fee = $_POST['hidden_competition_fee'];
$amount = $fee;

$pay = $this->instamojo->pay_request( 
                    $amount = $fee,
                $purpose = "Primary Colors International" , 
                $buyer_name = $profile_data['stud_name'] , 
                $email = $profile_data['stud_email'] , 
                $phone = $profile_data['stud_mobile'] ,
                    $send_email = 'TRUE' , 
                    $send_sms = 'TRUE' , 
                    $repeated = 'FALSE'

                );
```

Comment: No clear, can you please elaborate more. I am assuming that you are already got profile data from db and fee from a variable then just assign the values as param in the pay_request function.

Comment: $buyer_name = $profile_data['stud_name'],  when I am giving like this the values of this variable is not obtained inside the function pay_request() and not returning the value of redirect_url

Answer (score 0):

Pass values just like below. 
    $fee = $_POST['hidden_competition_fee'];
    $amount = $fee;

```
$pay = $this->instamojo->pay_request( 
                    $fee,
                "Primary Colors International" , 
                $profile_data['stud_name'] , 
                $profile_data['stud_email'] , 
                $profile_data['stud_mobile'] ,
                'TRUE' , 
                'TRUE' , 
                'FALSE'

                );
```

Assuming the model function is like.

```
function pay_request($amount,$purpose,$buyer_name,$email,$phone,$send_email,$send_sms,$repeated){}
```

Comment: then check all the variables if they are having values or not.

Comment: this is not a model function..it is functino in the library instamojo

Comment: can you please show the error log....if you are using ubuntu then you can find the error log by tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: or if you enabled log_threshold in the config you can view error log in application/logs folder but first you need to create this folder.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Passing Variable is not need to give a variable name in a value inside the `function()`

```
$pay = $this->instamojo->pay_request(
    $fee,
    "Primary Colors International" ,
    $profile_data['stud_name'] ,
    $profile_data['stud_email'] ,
    $profile_data['stud_mobile'] ,
    'TRUE' ,
    'TRUE' ,
    'FALSE'
);
```

**Second**

If the value is not successfully passed inside the `pay_request` function(), then you need to check. Is your variable contains a value?

Well check the `$profile_data` as well by using

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($profile_data);
echo "</pre>";
```